Man hears garbage men outside, goes outside, they shoot him
I believe this is at the beginning, or close to the beginning of the film. A man and woman are in bed and they hear the garbage truck going by their house, maybe the garbage truck runs over their mailbox and/or garbage.
The man runs outside to confront the garbage men and 2 of them on the back shoot him with machine guns.
It has an 80's/early 90's feel to it.

Hi. Was this film American? Do you remember anything else (like the general plot or at least the genre)?

It was American.

This is an early scene in Commando, starring Arnold Schwarzenegger as Colonel John Matrix.
Early in the movie, the bad guys assassinate several of Matrix's fellow soldiers, one by one -- including a guy who they shoot while he is taking out his trash.
IIRC it was the supposed sanitation employees on the back of the garbage-truck who shoot the victim.
update: here's the scene
